# Problems using Writer monad in ghci

Tags: haskell, monads

I am currently learing Haskell with the book *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* and got stuck with the scripts for *Log Number* and *Greatest Common Divisor* introducing the `Writer` monad. I understand what they do, but loading them in `ghci` results in an error. See: http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer

Below is the `logNumber` script and the error code I get:

```hs
-- Log Number
import Control.Monad.Writer  

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)
```

```
 error:
    * Data constructor not in scope:
        Writer :: (Int, [[Char]]) -> Writer [String] Int
    * Perhaps you meant one of these:
        `WriterT' (imported from Control.Monad.Writer),
        variable `writer' (imported from Control.Monad.Writer)
  |
5 | logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])
  |               ^^^^^^
```

I do not know why this is happening, as I copied the code from the example. Is the code faulty? Or has the `Control.Monad.Writer` library changed since the book was published? How can I fix the code?

I am using `haskell-platform` with `ghc 8.6.5`.

Comment: The acutal constructor is `WriterT (m (a, w))`. Probably is due to unupdated version of the book. just substitute `logNumber x = return  (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x]) `
`

Comment: @Ismor Or you could use the `writer` function, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Has the `Control.Monad.Writer` library changed since the book was published?

Yes, this is the problem. Since *LYAH* was published, the `Writer` monad has been changed; instead of being its own data type, it is now defined in terms of the *monad transformer* `WriterT`. Monad transformers are really useful, and this change gave a lot more flexibility, but it also meant that all the old tutorials are no longer correct. You can work around this by using the `writer` function instead of the `Writer` constructor: they have the same type, but `writer` is implemented in terms of the new `WriterT` type instead of the now-removed `Writer` constructor.